# msgpack dictionary with tuple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, msgpack

```py
import msgpack
path = 'test.msgpack'
with open(path, "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(msgpack.packb({ (1,2): 'str' }))
```

works fine, now

```py
with open(path, 'rb') as infile:
    print(msgpack.unpackb(infile.read()))
```

errors with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 195, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
ValueError: list is not allowed for map key
```

(Isn't it totally bizarre the error is only detected during unpacking?)

How can I write or workaround msgpacking a python dict with tuples as keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here: `msgpack` is using `strict_map_key=True` by default since version **1.0.0** ([source](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python#major-breaking-changes-in-msgpack-10)) and msgpack's arrays are implicitly converted to  Python's `lists` - which are not hashable. To make things work, pass the needed keyword arguments:

```py
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    print(msgpack.unpackb(f.read(), use_list=False, strict_map_key=False))

# outputs: {(1, 2): 'str'}
```